# .htaccess show contents of directory with another directory in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm looking to show directory contents of a subdirectory in another subdirectory with `$_GET` parameters. Here is an example:

**From:**

- https://example.com/john

**To:**

- https://example.com/user/index.php?username=john

I do not want it to redirect, just show the contents in `/user/index.php?username=john`.

I also want to make sure that if a file exists, then to show the file instead. For example, `https://example.com/about` will NOT show the `/user/...` directory because the page exists.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /user/index.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```